# How to do a perspective transformation of an image which is missing corners using opencv java

Tags: opencv, contour, hough-transform, canny-operator

I am trying to build a document scanner using openCV. I am trying to auto crop an uploaded image. I have few use cases where there is a gap in the border when the document is out of frame(captured image).

Ex image

[image: Original Image]

Below is the canny edge detection of the given image.

[image: Canny Edge Image]

The borders are missing here and findContours does not return me proper results due to this.
How can I handle such images.

Both automatic canny edge detection as well as dilate does not work in such cases because it can join only small edges.

Also few documents might have only 2 sides or 3 sides captured using camera and how can we crop the other areas which is not required.

Example Image:

[image]

Is there any specific technique for handling such documents?
Please suggest few ideas.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: @xszym Here is the code https://gist.github.com/sureshbabuinfo/f398a758dbbec64eee2d7c8221b0c970

Comment: @xszym Did you have a chance to look at the code?

Comment: I hope my answer help you in some way :)

Comment: You can try detecting the line borders using Hough Line transform. This will not give you the corners, but will give lines that you can extrapolate to find corners. Once you have lines for all four corners, compute their intersections. There should be 4 intersections and those are your corners. Pass this info to the Perspective Rectifier.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is unusual. One way to solve this problem which comes to my mind is to:

1. Add white borders around image.
   https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html
2. Find lines in edges

http://www.robindavid.fr/opencv-tutorial/chapter5-line-edge-and-contours-detection.html

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html

3. Make Probablistic HoughLines
4. Crop image by these lines. It will for sure work for image like 1st one.
   For image like 2nd one you can use perpendicular and parallel lines.

For sure your algorithm must be pretty complex to works good. The easiest way is to take a picture of whole document if it is possible.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already tried the border as you mentioned and it worked for the first image. The problem is the uploaded picture might have all four edges of the document or it might not. So I have to handle all the use cases in a different way. I just want to know whether there is any common technique to handle this.